# node js + html with ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, request

i have a  little problem
i have 2 files one for the server and other for the client

and the server code :

```js
//Le demmarage du serveur 

//les fonctions ON/OFF GPIO :
if (etat=="1"){on();}
if (etat=="0"){off();}
function on() {
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('ouss.txt', '1', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Replaced!');
});}
```

when i click the button the request will be send into a server and the server will insert 1 into a ouss.txt file but the problem is that the request will not sent

Comment: check the developer tools console in the browser - observe what happens when you click the button ... is it what you expect? do you see any errors like `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'` on page loading?

Answer (score 0):

the variable `etat` is never assigned, you need to read the `etat` from the query in the url and call the functions before `res.end()`

try this :

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    var q= url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    etat = q.etat;

    if (etat=="1"){ledon();}
    if (etat=="0"){ledoff();}

    res.end('Salut a tous votre serveur est en marche');
}).listen(1234, '127.1.1.1');
```

more details and examples : https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp